# Создание Web Анкеты JAVA+SPRING+Thymeleaf+JPA Hibernate. Не могу записать в базу данных Questions Id Questionnaires

Tags: java, веб-программирование, hibernate, thymeleaf

Всем привет!
Есть две таблицы в базе, Анкеты с их названиями и вопросы под каждую анкету, связь между ними реализовал One To Many. При создании вопроса через вэб не могу занести айдишник анкеты. Вот сущность Questions.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "questionnaire")
public class Questions {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String valueQuestion;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "choice_type")
    private Choice choiceType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn (name="questionnaire_id")
    private Questionnaires questionnaire;
```

Контроллер:

```
    @GetMapping("/questionnaire/{id}")
    public String createQuestion(@PathVariable Long id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("question", new Questions());
        Questionnaires questionnaire = questionnairesRepository.findById(id).get();
        model.addAttribute("questionnaire", questionnaire);
        return "/create_question";
    }

    @PostMapping("/create_question")
    public String addQuestion(@ModelAttribute("question") Questions question,
                              Model model){
        Optional<Questions> questionsFromBD = 
        questionsRepository.findByValueQuestion(question.getValueQuestion());
        if (questionsFromBD.isPresent()) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Question exists!");
            return "create_questionnaire";
        }
        question.setValueQuestion(question.getValueQuestion());
        questionsRepository.save(question);
        return "create_questionnaire";
    }
```

Html страница создания вопроса:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Create New Question</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
    You have been logged out.
</div>
<h1>Create New Question</h1>
<p th:text="${message}"></p>
<form th:action="@{/api/create_question}" method="post" >
    <label for="name">Enter Value: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{question.valueQuestion}" id="name"/>
    <br/>
    <h2>One or more response values </h2>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select th:field="*{question.choiceType}" >
            <option th:each="type : ${T(com.github.vilfenox.anketa.model.Choice).values()}"
                    th:value="${type}"
                    th:text="${type}">
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Questinnaire - </h2>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{question.questionnaire}"
                         th:text="${questionnaire.getNameQuestionnaire()}"
                         th:value="${questionnaire.id}"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create!"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот сам процесс: как я создал и записал в бд новую анкету, я хочу ее заполнить вопросами! нажимая по ссылке я перехожу на страницу создания вопроса, где ввожу сам вопрос, тип ответов (один или несколько вариантов ответа), а под капотом хочу чтобы еще этому вопросу присвоился айдишник анкеты, и все это пошло в базу.

Предполагаю что ошибка кроется где-то в этой части кода:

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{question.questionnaire}"
                         th:text="${questionnaire.getNameQuestionnaire()}"
                         th:value="${questionnaire.id}"/>
```

Менял `th:value` на `"${questionnaire}"` `"${questionnaire.getId()}"` , выдает  всю туже ошибку:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: значение NULL в столбце "questionnaire_id" отношения "questions" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL
> Подробности: Ошибочная строка содержит (21, Любимый жанр, PLENTY, null).

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, подозреваю что все просто решается)

Comment: На какую ссылку нажимаешь? Где эта ссылка у тебя в коде создаётся?

Comment: @Roman C  
ссылка создается с сайта со списком анкет:   `  
    th:each="questionnaire : ${questionnaires}">  
    <a th:href="@{/api/questionnaire/{id}(id=${questionnaire.getId()})}"   
    th:text="${questionnaire.getNameQuestionnaire()}">questionnaire</a>  `

Comment: Значит  id передается в url. Если он не передается, то работать не будет.

Comment: он передается в юрл , потом через @PathVariable в контролере я по нему извлекаю сущность анкеты, и пытаюсь его айдишник занести в бд сущности вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начало работать с такими изменениями:

```
<input type="hidden"
       th:text="${questionnaire.getNameQuestionnaire()}"
       th:value="${questionnaire.id}" th:name="questionnaire"
```